# Main form is always stealing focus, when child form is created out of treeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I've the following problem:
My program (Winforms) has a main window with a treeView control.
When the user selects a node in the treeView a new child window shall be created.

This works just fine.
But the problem is, that after this child window has become visible, the main window comes to front and partially hides this child window.

I've build a little mockup in order to make sure that it is not only related to my program:

```
namespace FatherAndSon
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Son aNewSon = new Son();
        aNewSon.Visible = true;
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        Son aNewSon = new Son();
        aNewSon.Visible = true;
    }
}
}
```

When I press the button1, all is fine but when I select a node in the treeView, the main window jumps to the front immediately after the child form appeared.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Visible = true` to `.Show(this)` -> this change will make that child window will always be on top of it's `Parent` (main window in this case).

```
Son aNewSon = new Son();
aNewSon.Show(this);
```

if it is not acceptable that child form is always on top of it's parent then change it to:

```
Son aNewSon = new Son();
aNewSon.Visible = true;
aNewSon.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

To have "aNewSon" always on top, you can also try to add the "TopMost" property to the newly created form:

```
aNewSon.TopMost = true;
```

Check [Msdn about TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3bf6504%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parent form to the constructor try use "Show" method instead of visible=true.

```
    Son aNewSon = new Son();
    aNewSon.Show(this);
```

may be, than you can also call BringToFront method `Application.OpenForms["Form1"].BringToFront();`

in your case:

```
    Son aNewSon = new Son();
    aNewSon.Show(this);
    aNewSon.BringToFront();
```